# In JavaScript, I have an error in calling functions, variables, and displaying those variables

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a clicker game. When I display the `moneyCurrent` variable I get incorrect numbers. The numbers don't actually join. This is in the `sellTech()` function.

If you want the full project go to [enter link description here](https://repl.it/@beraEmirKoklu/) techClicker

This is on `repl.it` and that is not the problem.

> I have tried parseInt() and Number() and the numbers keep adding like
>   they are strings.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
<title>Tech Clicker</title>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="IMAGE"/>
<link href="techClicker.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

<h1>Tech Clicker</h1>

<h2 id="moneyValueText">$0</h2>

<div id="ccDiv">
    <input id="ccMakeButton"type="image" src="IMAGE"
onclick="ccClickFunc()" width="50"
height="50">
    <p> </p>
    <button id="ccSellButton"onclick="sellTech()">Sell Computer 
Chips</button>
    <h4 id="ccCounter">Computer Chips = </h4>
</div>

<div id="usbDiv">
    <input id="mcMakeButton"type="image" 


src="IMAGE"
onclick="mcClickFunc()" width="38"
height="26">
    <p> </p>
    <button id="mcSellButton"onclick="sellTech()">Sell Memory Chips</button>
    <h4 id="mcCounter">Memory Chips = </h4>
</div>

<script src="clickGainFunc.js"></script>
<script src="sellTechV2.js"></script>
</body>

</html>

var ccPrice = 0.25
var ccSellAmount
var mcPrice = 0.35;
var mcSellAmount;


//JAVASCRIPT

function sellTech(){
ccSellAmount = cc * ccPrice;
mcSellAmount = mc * mcPrice;
moneyCurrent = ccSellAmount + mcSellAmount;
document.getElementById("moneyValueText").innerHTML = moneyCurrent;
cc = 0;
mc = 0;
document.getElementById("ccCounter").innerHTML = "Computer Chips = " + cc;
document.getElementById("mcCounter").innerHTML = "Memory Chips = " + mc;
}
```

I expected that the numbers would add up and not drop in value.
This is a little hard to explain so go to 
https://techclicker--beraemirkoklu.repl.co/
and then click on the computer chip once. And then sell it. 0.25. If you sell 2, 0.5. if you sell 1, again .25. I am trying to fix that too.

Comment: when exactly do you get undefined? I went to your link (not good practice for SO) and didn't manage to get any NaN or undefined